# RavenDB: How to create MapReduce index to return a filtered list of child objects

Tags: ravendb, indexing

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9468253/29555)

I have the following document structure:

```
Game 
 - Id
 - Teams
   - Team 1
     - list of players
   - Team 2 
     - list of players
 - Events
   - Event 1
     - type: Pass
     - teamId
     - PlayerId
   - Event 2
     - type: Goal
     - teamId
     - PlayerId
```

How do I build an index that gives me all the events for a player for a given game?

Here is how far I got and RavenDB says it can't understand my query?

```
public class Games_PlayerEvents : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Game, Games_PlayerEvents.ReduceResult>
    {
        public class ReduceResult
        {
            public string PlayerId { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<GameEvent> Events { get; set; }
        }


        public Games_PlayerEvents()
        {
            Map = games => from game in games
                           select new
                           {
                               PlayerId = "",
                               Events = game.Events
                           };

            Reduce = results => from result in results
                                from @event in result.Events
                                group @event by @event.PlayerId into playerEvents
                                select new
                                {
                                    PlayerId = playerEvents.Key,
                                    Events = playerEvents.Select(g => g)
                                };


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marto, in case you *really* want to model it this way, you don't need to create an index, as you can load the whole game document and do the rest using standard linq-to-objects aggregations.

Anyway, it sounds as if you want to have Game, Player and Event as independant documents as these are your aggregate roots or in other words - they have a meaning on their own.

Comment: Fair point. However the players are not full entities but just a name and an id so I don't think they should live outside the Game object. I was thinking originally of splitting the events into a GameEvents object because they get updated most often throughout a game but I'll still have similar problems. Do you think I really need to separate the model to be able to query it.

Comment: No, you don't need an index at all to query it, so modeling it in seperate documents was just a suggestion. As I said above, you're good with just loading the document and doing normal linq-queries.